# Why does one have to use CALayer's presentationLayer for hit-testing?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I was working on a Cocoa Touch application, and trying to handle touches by determining which sublayer of a view's layer was touched. My controller's code looked like this:

```
CALayer *hitLayer = [self.view.layer hitTest:point];
```

This wasn't working. It would work if I tapped at the bottoms of sublayers, but not at the tops. After an hour of hair-pulling and Googling, I finally figured out that it works if one uses the presentation layer to do the hit-testing instead of the layer itself:

```
CALayer *hitLayer = [self.view.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point];
```

So, I've solved my problem, but my question is: Why?

I've read through the Core Animation guide, and I understand that the presentation tree and rendering tree can differ from the object-model tree. But I don't understand why the presentation tree would (apparently) have different hit-testing behavior.  Wouldn't the presentation tree and object-model have the same frames, bounds, etc.?

Comment: What is the class of self.view : UIView or CALayer ?

Comment: self.view is a UIView. I've corrected the code above to use "self.view.layer" as it should have been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CALayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), there seems to be a difference between the model and the presentation tree regarding what is presented to the user (depending on the ongoing animation). For hit testing, there is a reference in the `presentationLayer` method:

> For example, sending a hitTest:
>   message to the presentationLayer will
>   query the presentation values of the
>   layer tree.

So I suspect that only presentation layer has the right geometry information to perform the hit test.

Answer (score 3):

Kristopher, I had a very similar issue too. However, when I converted the point to the super layer or super views coordinate system it worked perfectly. I did not use the presentation layer.

```
    //Identify the touch point in the view. Using UITapRecognizer
CGPoint loc = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];

//convert the point to superview co-ordinates and then identify the layer using hit test.
CALayer *layer = [self.layer hitTest:[self convertPoint:loc toView:self.superview]];
```

This returns me the layer that was touched, at least for now. Let us know if you think this is a wrong approach and I should be using presentation-layer instead.