# Problem returning a custom CALayer subclass from hitTest

Tags: cocoa, subclass, calayer

I’m trying to identify custom CALayer subclasses via hittesting. 
That works fine with one exception:

My custom CALayers represent text windows and all the data (content, background color, position, ...) are taken from a NSManagedObjects (from CoreData). My CALayer subclass saves it’s related managedObject class in an instance variable.
The Problem is: I can't access this ivar:

When I check like so:

```
CustomCALayer *customLayer =[self.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:mouseDownPosition];
```

...the customLayer contains all the attributes, that `CALayer` has, (like `backgroundColor` or `name`) but not my managedObject ivar.
I suspect that this happens because hitTest returns `CALayer` and not my subclass.

But how can I get around that?

(I also tried to hittest a „hitTestLayer“ sublayer of my layer and then get the layer via `hitTestLayer.superlayer`. But, well, `superlayer` also returns `CALayer`...)

Answer (score 0):

Did you override the custom CALayer's - hitTest method to return CustomCALayer instead of CALayer?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clue! But I still can't figure out how to do that. Is it very stupid to try:    - (CustomCALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint
{
 return (CustomCALayer *) [super hitTest:thePoint];
}
?

Comment: I was thinking about it and that could work, but first, did you make that ivar a property? If not, you won't be able to retrieve it anyways.

Comment: Also, how are you testing what class your returned object is? For testing you might consider logging isKindOfClass... that will help you find out what's going on?

Comment: Yes the ivar is a property and I tested the class of the object via isKindOfClass now. I think, I probably misinterpreted the problem, when I thought that hitTest would return the wrong class (damn, I'm sorry!): the class is right, but the ivar still doesn't exist. But here is something interesting: As I described in my question, I sent hitTest to "self.layer.presentationLayer". When I change that to "self.layer", suddenly my ivar exists! I think that solves the problem for me (since I don't want to animate my layers) but I still don't understand it. Anyway, thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I imagine returned layer was not containing the ivar because it wasn't returning the right layer! You should be sending hitTest to the root layer. Sorry I missed that! :( But it sounds like you got it working. 

However, if you do want to send hitTest to a subLayer, you have to call it with objectAtIndex first. A sublayer is not a member of the layer so you don't call it with dot syntax. It belongs to the NSArray member called sublayers. So you would do 

CACustomLayer *customLayer = [self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:i] hitTest:thePoint]. 

Anyways, glad you got it working!

Comment: Wait. I'm confused. Was presentationLayer just the root layer of the view?

Comment: That presentationLayer is supposed to be the presentationLayer of the root layer of the view. I read one should test that instead of the layer itself here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199171/why-does-one-have-to-use-calayers-presentationlayer-for-hit-testing and in the pragmatic book "Core Animation for MacOS X and the iPhone". Somehow that doesn't work. Also confusing is the compiler warning: "incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSView *', expected 'struct CALayer *' " which I overlooked before. I suspect a very stupid failure by myself somewhere there...

Comment: Bill Dudney has taught me a lot!

Maybe hitTest on presentation layer is unique to touch events. I always just hitTest the root layer, but then I do mostly OSX! There are lots of funny, interesting particulars to learn.

I am convinced... there are no 'stupid' failures when writing code. You either know how to do it, or you don't know...yet! Even the guys who seem to know it all had to learn somewhere, sometime. They act like knowing how to do something is because they are really smart, when a lot of it is just muscle memory. But hey, better to tread lightly I guess. Veterans can be ruthless.