# Buttons that move on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, move

I want to have multiple buttons on the screen that continuously move. When they touch the sides, they should bounce back. How do i do this? Any helpful links? Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you go through the apple animation document.

[Introduction to Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Check the following SO post.

[How to move several buttons throughout the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983216/how-to-move-several-buttons-throughout-the-screen)

[Move a button in the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028879/move-a-button-in-the-screen)

Comment: @Appster :Glad to hear it help you .

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at cocos2d which i think may make it easier to do something like this if they have to constantly be moving.

cocos2d is a game platform which has physics etc but also i believe has support for buttons so it should not be hard to achieve something like this. Check out the cocos2d website and documentation.